# StreamReader took long time to get the SSHclient command execution output in Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

After I execute the command using sshclient, the output will be writing to the text box at the same time. Here I'm using streamreader after execute the command.
My requirement is at the executing time itself I need to write the output to the RichTextbox.

```
var error = string.Empty;
using (var client = new SshClient(host, SuspenseConstants.Port, user, passwrd))
{
    client.Connect();
    var command = client.RunCommand(script);
    var reader = new StreamReader(command.ExtendedOutputStream);
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var output = reader.ReadLine();
        reprocessResult.txtReprocessingDetail.AppendText(output + " \r\n");
        reprocessResult.txtReprocessingDetail.Update();
        if (output != null && output.Contains("ERROR"))
        {
            error = output;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: you can add the code within the question using Code block .

Comment: Copied code from image to code segment as text

Answer (score 0):

You are reading line by line and have a sleep for 100ms after each line is read thats why its taking time. No other reason

Comment: can you please tell me how to handle this??? i need to display the output in Richtextbox while command  executing time itself...

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to display the contents line by line rather than reading at once and writing them to the textbox?

Comment: Please elaborate what is your issue

Comment: First i will pass my command to Runcommand() and the response whatever coming i will display it line by line in Richtextbox. Actually this scenario is working fine. my issue is after ran my command the response displaying is take more time. Response should display when executing the command time itself. its like command prmt.

Comment: yes if i removed sleep, the all output text are displaying as single time. but i need to display as line by line as command executing. ex. if u pass "ping www.google.com" command in cmd promt the response will display line by line like that i need. but my posted code working fine only issue is the start displaying the response is took more time that's it.